# MySql join 3 tables - Multiple join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

[image: db image]

```
SELECT type_files.html_embed_before
   , script_files.path
   , type_files.html_embed_after
FROM type_files
INNER JOIN script_files ON (type_files.type = script_files.type)
```

the above code gives me information for all script_files.
I want to build on the query and get

- script_files.id = script_match.file_id
- script_matches.ap_id equal to article.head, header.head OR footer.head.
- The Id for article, header, footer will be passed in

Comment: [Close] It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I agree it was a bit vague/difficult to understand, but I have hope for this question. The diagram (hopefully) helped me to decipher it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement I'm least understanding is your link from script_match to article, header, and footer.  This should be what you want if I understand correctly.

```
SELECT tf.html_embed_before
   , sf.path
   , tf.html_embed_after
FROM type_files AS tf
INNER JOIN script_files AS sf ON tf.type = sf.type
INNER JOIN script_match AS sm ON sf.Id = sm.file_id
WHERE sm.ap_id IN
(
   SELECT a.head
   FROM article AS a
   WHERE a.id = @yourId

   UNION ALL

   SELECT h.head
   FROM header AS h
   WHERE h.id = @yourId

   UNION ALL

   SELECT f.head
   FROM footer AS f
   WHERE f.id = @yourId
)
```

[MySQL JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) documentation

[Jeff Atwood's Coding Horror article on Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: yes that's the answer i asked..
Any links for join's tutorial available?
I take 9/10 in this lesson to my university but long time ago..
:(

Comment: I have posted a link to the MySQL join documentation, as well as a good article (with pictures) about joins.  If you do not like these, or want more information, just google `mysql join tutorial`